# How can I find the values of $a$ for which the function $f(x) = e^x-\ln(x+a)-a>0$, $\forall x \in (-a, + \infty)$.

Tags: calculus, functions

The title is self explanatory. I am given the function:

$$f(x) = e^x - \ln(x+ a)-a \hspace{2cm} f:(-a, +\infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$$

where $a \in \mathbb{R}$ and I have to find the set of values of $a$ for which the function $f(x)$ is always $>0$. The answer given in my textbook is $a \in (-\infty, 1)$, but I don't see how was this answer reached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a<1$, then using $e^t\ge 1+t$ with $t=x$ and with $t=\ln(x+a)$, we find
$$\begin{align} e^x-\ln(x+a)-a&\ge 1+x-\ln(x+a)-a\\
&>x+a-\ln(x+a)-a\\
&=e^{\ln(x+a)}-\ln(x+a)-a\\
&\ge 1-a\\&>0\end{align}$$
for all $x$, 
showing that the condition holds at least for all $a\in(-\infty,1)$.

If $a\ge1$, say $a=1+y$ with $y\ge 0$, we find
$$ f(0)=e^0-\ln(1+y)-1-y=-\ln(1+y)-y\le 0,$$
showing that the condition does not hold for any $a\ge1$.

Comment: Very very good and my compliments for your score.